# Convert Circuit to Lower Battery

Tags: amplifier

I have a circuit that was originally intended for 12 volts. I am new to electronics and would like to know the best way to modify the components to work with a 9v battery. I know it can work because the LM386 chip has a wide range of possible input voltage. The site is here and the circuit below:[Site](http://www.instructables.com/id/Ultra-Sensitive-Spy-Ear/?&sort=ACTIVE&limit=40&offset=40#DISCUSS).  [image]

[EDIT] I understand the datasheet but was wondering if changing any components would increase final mW output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick peek at the [LM386 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) says it works with power supply between 4 and 12V. you will just get lower output power, which is also spec'd: at 9V supply and an 8ohm load, you get 700mW typical from the output, as opposed to 1W using a 12V supply.

Comment: Also the outputs will be clamped (distorted) at lower values..

Comment: Would changing a resistor or capacitor increase output mW? I know it is probably a dumb question but I am a newbie.

Comment: Nope, won't help. It's physics! Power = voltage x current. lower voltage means lower power (assuming the same load resistance).